# My Notification bar won't roll up ?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, touchscreen, motorola-defy, notification-bar

I am using Motorola Defy Android 2.2. But I am facing a problem with touch screen. The buttons at very lower end of the screen don't work i.e touch at the very lower end don't work. That's why after pulling downing the notification bar I am unable to roll it up back. I am even unable to use apps that have small buttons at very end of the screen. To use them I have to rotate the phone.

Please help me out.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. How old is the device? Any chance for a warrantee repair?

Comment: Its merely two months old.

Comment: I think you need to take it back to where you bought it and get a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Like Al said, it's most likely a hardware problem, but to address the title question: you can roll the notification area up with the back button.

Comment: Yeah doing the same thing. But to use buttons in that area has become difficult.